# unable to connect with a Server over the WAN using Client Server approach?

Tags: c#, client-server

I am working on simple Client Server Application, it is just like a chat Messenger.
I am using Client Server approach. My application works fine on LAN Local Area Network.but when it try to communicate to sever out side the LAN. Then there is no response to Client. while i know the server IP Address (through an external means ) which uses a broad band connection and resides on a WAN.
i think i am unable to resolve the IP address, or proxy like problem occurs.
Can anybody Help me out ?
Regards !
Sm.Abdullah

```
//
/*   Server Program    */

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class serv {
    public static void Main() {
    try {
        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("172.21.5.99");
         // use local m/c IP address, and 
         // use the same in the client

/* Initializes the Listener */
        TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,8001);

/* Start Listeneting at the specified port */        
        myList.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");    
        Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + 
                          myList.LocalEndpoint );
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

        Socket s=myList.AcceptSocket();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

        byte[] b=new byte[100];
        int k=s.Receive(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
        for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

        ASCIIEncoding asen=new ASCIIEncoding();
        s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
        Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
/* clean up */            
        s.Close();
        myList.Stop();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
    }    
    }

}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*       Client Program      */

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;


public class clnt {

    public static void Main() {

        try {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");
            // here is local ip.. 
            // if i replace it with WAN IP it does not communicate.
            tcpclnt.Connect("172.21.5.99",8001);
            // use the ipaddress as in the server program

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

            String str=Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba=asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

            byte[] bb=new byte[100];
            int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);

            for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            tcpclnt.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably your server port is blocked by firewall.

Comment: no..it is not. let me more specific.
Server is reside on a LAN all the Computer having Same Public IP or WAN IP because they are connected with same modem. in this situation how the client will communicate to server ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the firewall / router?

Most of the time unsolicited incoming connections are dismissed and will fail because they could be malicious in origin and nature.

You can however get around some of these issues by looking into NAT traversal

see: [tcp client to communicate with server present in different network (NAT issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342915/tcp-client-to-communicate-with-server-present-in-different-network-nat-issue)